# How to deserialize 2 elements into one type, then serialize back to only 1 element

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have the following:

```
<XmlArray("lines")> _
<XmlArrayItem("CalculatedLine", GetType(Lines.CalculatedLine))> _
<XmlArrayItem("PointLine", GetType(Lines.PointLine))> _
<XmlArrayItem("line", GetType(Lines.PointLine))> _
Public Property lines As List(Of Lines.Line) = New List(Of Lines.Line)
```

As you can see, Array Elements `PointLine` and `line` *should* deserialize to type `PointLine`. I get an exception, as expected:

`Ambiguous types specified for member 'lines'.  Items 'line' and 'PointLine' have the same type.  Please consider using XmlElementAttribute with XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute instead.`

The key here is that when I *serialize* the data again, both `Line`s and `PointLine`s should be serialized as `PointLine`.

This is to maintain backwards compatability with older versions of the XML file.

I've done some looking and have come accross `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`. Before I go investing loads of time to learn how to use it, can it do what I need? Is it the easiest solution? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You should delete your old, almost identical question

Comment: @ProGrammer HA! I forgot I even asked that!

Comment: Do you have a constructor that creates a (shallow copy  of a) `PointLine` from a `Line` and vice versa?  The easiest way to handle this would be to remap to the older more general type on the fly during serialization.

Comment: @dbc Sorry i'm not quite sure what you mean by "remap". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart - you wrote *both Lines and PointLines should be serialized as PointLine.  This is to maintain backwards compatability with older versions of the XML file.*  It sounds as though you introduced Line as a variant of PointLine in a later version of your software.  Can Line be converted to PointLine without loss of data?  Is it possible to determine when a PointLine is a Line, and convert to a Line?  Guess: PointLine is a polyline of N points while Line is a special case with only two points.

Comment: @dbc Actually `PointLine` was introduced to allow for `CalculatedLine` to be introduced. Both are technically lines, so they inherit from a base class `Line`. The `<line ...>` tags in the XML are *identical* to the `<PointLine ...>` tags. They refer to exactly the same class in code, `PointLine`. I tried creating a class for the *old* `lines` and converting them to `PointLines`, but I cant get the conversion to stick... When watching the objects, they never actually become `PointLines`...

Comment: @dbc Oh and PointLines and Lines are both just lines described by 2 or more points. They are the same things.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have two different element names map to the same `Type` in a polymorphic collection by using [`<XmlChoiceIdentifier>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute.aspx), however it is somewhat inconvenient in your case because:

1. `XmlChoiceIdentifier` only seems to work with *arrays* whereas you are using a `List(Of Lines.Line)`.  Thus a surrogate array property will be required.
2. `XmlChoiceIdentifier` only works with arrays that are formatted without an outer container element (i.e. that have [`<XmlElement("line", GetType(Lines.PointLine))>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attributes applied) whereas you are using [`XmlArrayArrribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx) to indicate an outer container element should be used.  Thus you must nest your surrogate array property inside yet another surrogate container to get the correct level of nesting.

   It is easier to use a `Structure` for this surrogate since `XmlSerializer` will set it back inside the container type only after it is completely populated.  If the surrogate were to be a `Class` it would get set back as soon as it is constructed - i.e. before the array is actually read in.
3. You will also need to create an `Enum` whose element names correspond to all possible element names inside the polymorphic collection, and create a property that returns an array of enum values in 1-1 correspondence with the array of `Line` objects.

Thus, if your `Line` class hierarchy is defined as follows:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class Line
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property LineChoiceType As LineChoiceType  
End Class

Public Class CalculatedLine
    Inherits Line
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property LineChoiceType As LineChoiceType
        Get
            Return LineChoiceType.CalculatedLine
        End Get
    End Property        
End Class

Public Class PointLine
    Inherits Line
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property LineChoiceType As LineChoiceType
        Get
            Return LineChoiceType.line
        End Get
    End Property        
End Class

<XmlType(IncludeInSchema := false)> _
Public Enum LineChoiceType
    line
    CalculatedLine
    PointLine
End Enum
```

Note that I have each concrete subtype of `Line` returning its `LineChoiceType`.  You could choose a different method to map the type to the `LineChoiceType`, such as an extension method, if you prefer.

You can serialize and deserialize a list of lines belonging to a class named, say, `Document`, in the required format as follows:

```vb
Public Class Document

    <XmlIgnore> _
    Public Property lines As List(Of Lines.Line) = New List(Of Lines.Line)

    <XmlElement("lines")> _
    Public Property LinesListSurrogate as LinesListSurrogate
        Get
            Dim surrogate as new LinesListSurrogate
            If (lines IsNot Nothing) Then
                surrogate.LinesArray = lines.ToArray()
            End If
            return surrogate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As LinesListSurrogate)
            If Value.LinesArray IsNot Nothing
                If lines is Nothing
                    lines = New List(Of Lines.Line)(Value.LinesArray.Length)
                End If
                lines.AddRange(Value.LinesArray)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Structure LinesListSurrogate
    <XmlElement("CalculatedLine", GetType(Lines.CalculatedLine))> _
    <XmlElement("PointLine", GetType(Lines.PointLine))> _
    <XmlElement("line", GetType(Lines.PointLine))> _
    <XmlChoiceIdentifier("LinesChoice")> _
    Public Property LinesArray As Lines.Line()

    <XmlIgnore> _   
    Public Property LinesChoice as Lines.LineChoiceType()
        Get
            If LinesArray Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            End If
            Return LinesArray.Select(Function(l as Lines.Line) If(l Is Nothing, Lines.LineChoiceType.line, l.LineChoiceType)).ToArray()
        End Get
        Set
            ' Do nothing - don't care
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure
```

This code can successfully deserialize the following XML containing both `<PointLine>` and `<line>` elements:

```
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <lines>
    <CalculatedLine />
    <PointLine />
    <line />
  </lines>
</Document>
```

And re-serialize it with only `<line>` elements:

```
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <lines>
    <CalculatedLine />
    <line />
    <line />
  </lines>
</Document>
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UqxCkz).